# Free online survey and diary software for conducting experience sampling studies

Tags: developmental-psychology, personality, software, internet, survey

Are there any open source online survey software that enable researchers to use experience-sampling methods, e.g. online diaries (where people answer similar survey questions repeatedly and are notified and reminded)? Free, but not open source, would also be interesting.

Please only post solutions, that you have actually used for experience-sampling research, not ones that "might be easily adapted".

Comment: There are so many of these out there, is it even worth discussing this?

Comment: @jon Name one. I'm in this field and I don't share your perception.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that in your question text you specify "open source" solutions. I'm not aware of any open source solutions.

Comment: For commercial solutions I only know Qualtrics and I heard they're also fairly new to this, ie apparently you can't get a mobile experience sampling app going in a week. But yes I'm looking for open source, though simply free ones wouldn't hurt either. I'm not aware of any either. @Jon

Comment: for commercial ones, I've used Revelation from KDA and have seen demos of Luminosity and Qualvu... not free. Most survey companies will be willing to "fake it" by manually sending notifications to an online or mobile panel. Why the interest in open-source particularly - for academia?

Comment: @Jon Because we've got an internal solution at my uni that we consider releasing into open source, but it will be a lot of work and if we'd be reinventing a less well-rounded wheel... That was clearer in the original question which was closed, because whether it's worth the effort is subjective. Revelation and Qualvu seem to be oriented towards qualitative research, I couldn't find Luminosity easily.

Comment: Ruben, your profile says you're from Germany. Almost all surveys that come in through our mailing list are created on http://www.unipark.info or https://www.soscisurvey.de. Both are free for non-commercial use. I don't know what they can do, but maybe you want to take a look.

Comment: @what Thanks! Yes, I get those mails too. They're free (for a limited number of replies I think), but not open source. Also, I think they don't offer diary features.

Comment: I would simply let the users fill in the same questionnaire repeatedly (e.g. "How did you feel today?"). Ask them to enter a personal code on the first page, so you can match data sets, and save a timestamp with each reply (or ask the users to give the date the entry refers to, if they can fill in data for a non-current day). This was recommended in the SoSci Survey forum: http://forum.onlineforschung.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2927 Also, see a question that was asked on the Unipark forum: http://forum.unipark.info/showthread.php?t=7943 Not extremely elegant, but just to show you it is possible.

Comment: @what Yeah, you can also work around such limitations, but of course it's nicer if the platform handles it natively and there's not so much potential for user error and all that.

Comment: @Ruben Definitely! But from your comment above you are not looking for an actual solution, but want to compare the good tool you have with whatever makeshift solution is currently available. So this is what German students might use, and now you must decide if the increase in usability is large enough to justify your development cost.

Answer (score 4):

The best review of experience sampling tools I've found is [here](http://vjkhan.com/old/content/publications/ExperienceSampling-A-workbook-about-the-method-and-the-tools-that-support-it.pdf).

Specifically, to answer you question, check out ["MyExperience"](http://myexperience.sourceforge.net). To quote the website:

> MyExperience is a BSD-licensed open source mobile data collection tool
>   developed for Windows Mobile devices (including PDAs and mobile
>   phones) using .NET CF 2 and Microsoft SQL Compact Edition.
>
> MyExperience is available for free on SourceForge in beta release.
>   Please see our wiki for documentation and our blog for updates.
>   MyExperience combines sensing and self-report to collect both
>   quantitative and qualitative data on human behaviors, attitudes and
>   activities in the field. Using a mobile phone's wireless connectivity
>   to the internet, researchers have the ability to access MyExperience
>   data as it's collected allowing for ongoing analysis of study data and
>   early detection of subject compliance or technology issues.
>
> MyExperience is based on a three tier architecture of sensors,
>   triggers and actions; triggers use sensor event data to conditionally
>   launch actions. One novel aspect of MyExperience is that its behavior
>   and user interface are specified via XML and a lightweight scripting
>   language similar to the HTML/JavaScript paradigm on the web.

Comment: MyExperience works with Windows phones only, so that's a quite limited userbase, but it looks like it has an impressive feature set.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit old but there is a free iOS app called the PIEL Survey. It is in the App store. [There is a web site which explains how to set up Experience Sampling surveys.](http://pielsurvey.org)